# How to order entries from a many2one field?

Tags: odoo, field, many-to-one

So i have a field called Shipments, it's a `many2one` field. When you click it,  it shows lots of shipment dates and  the first entries are shipments from 2016.

Is there any way i can order them somehow that when i click there first entries will be  2017 ?

[image]

Here is a picture, sorry i didn't manage to put it right here in the message.

I'm new in this and need some help.

Comment: One more info, the data displayed is a string that contains name of the day and dates. I need that entries from current year to be the first that shows when i click Shipments field. User needs to click everytime that field and write there "2017"  to get entries from 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your *'Shipments'* model add

```
_order = 'your_date_field DESC'
```

Where *your_date_field* is the displayed date.

Comment: Hello again, this didn't solved my problem. That's because that field is displayed in form view and what you showed me is for tree view, i'm right ? Still looking for an answer..thanks !

Comment: Actually what I showed you tells odoo to order the records in the recordset by that specific field. It should work on every view.
Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it should..first i ordered records as you said  and as i want and than they apeared as it should in that select field. I will mark this as resolved.